# Grep: Finding in which functions a function is called

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, grep

Let's say I have a folder with numerous modules, and I'm doing a `grep` for a function. Let's say the function I'm searching for is called `test()`. Is it possible to find out which functions `test()` is called in? For example, let's say below is `ModuleA.erl`, and we do a grep for `test()`.

```
FunctionA()
   A = 5, 
   B = 3,
   test()
```

It should return:

```
ModuleA.erl: FunctionA()
```

It is safe to assume that the function definition will always be non-indented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk -v patt="test" '$0 ~ /^\w/ {f=$0} $0 ~ patt {print f}' file
FunctionA()
```

#### Explanation

This stores the lines not starting with a space. If a line matches, then it prints the last stored line.

- `-v patt="test"` provide the pattern
- `$0 ~ /^\w/ {f=$0}` if the current line starts with some character (not space), store its value.
- `$0 ~ patt {print f}` if a line contains the given pattern, print the stored header.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
FunctionA()
   A = 5, 
   B = 3,
   test()
FunctionB()
   A = 5, 
   B = 3,
   another()
$ awk -v patt="test" '$0 ~ /^\w/ {f=$0} $0 ~ patt {print f}' a
FunctionA()
```

Comment: Very nice solution and even better explanation +1

Answer (score 1):

Just run the below grep command on the directory where the `.erl` files are stored.

```
grep -HPoz '^\S.*(?=(\n .*)+test\(\))' *.erl
```

From `man grep`

```
-H, --with-filename       print the file name for each match
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
-z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start. `\S` matches any non-space character.`.*` matches any character but not of line breaks, zero or more times. `(?=(\n .*)+test\(\))` Positive lookahead assertion which asserts that the match must be followed by

- `\n .*` A new line character and a space followed by any number of characters,
- `(\n .*)+` one or more times.
- `test\(\)` and must have a `test()` string. Match will occur only if this condition was satisfied.

**Test:**

```
Folder$ cat gi.erl
FunctionA()
       A = 5, 
       B = 3,

FunctionB()
       A = 5, 
       B = 3,
       test()
Folder$ cat ri.erl
FunctionA()
   A = 5, 
   B = 3,
   test()
FunctionB()
   A = 5, 
   B = 3,
Folder$ grep -HPoz '^\S.*(?=(\n .*)+test\(\))' *.erl
gi.erl:FunctionB()
ri.erl:FunctionA()
```

Here `Folder` is the folder name where all the `erl` files are stored.

Comment: this is a very good answer! I wouldn't have imagined `grep` could solve this. +1 for the explanation as well